# Unity PostProcess Build script fails when running from command line

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

I am trying to build my project from the command line targeting iOS.
When I build this from the editor, everything works! I have a PostProcess build script that I use.

When I try to build form the command line using the following command:
**/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -executeMethod BuildScript.BuildIOS -nographics -buildTarget iOS**

I am getting an error from my PostProcess build script saying:
**Assets/Editor/MyBuildPostprocessor.cs(9,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Xcode' does not exist in the namespace`UnityEditor.iOS'. Are you missing an assembly reference?**

The line that generates the error is a simple using clause:

```
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
```

So it seems that for some reason, the command line build mechanism does not recognise the UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode assembly, and my PostProcess build script cannot run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known case when iOS project is built manually in Unity without errors and fails building on build-server (Unity cloud, Jenkins, TeamCity and others). I think that your case is similar with it. Because if you take a look at the build-server process of building Unity app you'll see that it also uses command line command

> /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -executeMethod BuildScript.BuildIOS -nographics -buildTarget iOS

As for build-server issue, the solution is to put all your post-process scripts inside `#if UNITY_IOS` condition. And it's possible that you've misunderstood the error you get. Unity says that it doesn't understand `XCode` namespace while trying to include your post-process script inside your build. And of course, Unity can't include `XCode` namespace because it's available in Unity Editor only.

So try adding  `#if UNITY_IOS` at the very beginning of your post-process source, even before using section and `#endif` the the very end of the source. In this case Unity won't compile post-process script during building phase, but will call your post-process script after XCode project will be created.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information why manual and command line build processes differ.

Comment: Thank you @vmchar for answering. My post-process script already includes a #if UNITY_IOS condition around it, so it's not that..

Comment: I found that the parameter `-buildTarget iOS` was the only way to make Unity actually define `UNITY_IOS`. Without it, the define was not there and our builds would fail because of it.